# Is object space the same as local space?

Tags: directx11, terminology

I was in directx 11 and was wondering is local space the same as object space and if not, what is object space?

Comment: As far as I know, they're the same

Comment: just a word that is applied in the area of texturing right? tbn basis texture the object?

Answer (score 2):

"Object space" is generally used to refer to the coordinate space that a model or collection of geometry is defined within. Another way to think of this would be the space that the object was created in, where the origin is some useful point within or relative to the object, such as its center, or the place where the model would "touch the ground" when positioned in the world, et cetera.

"Local space" is sometimes synonymous with object space, if you're talking geometry. However, in some specialized contexts it could also be used to refer to any other coordinate system if there is an important distinction to be made between "this" system (the local one) and "that" system (the other one). However this will generally be made apparent explicitly or from the context.

Assuming "local space" refers to "object space" is probably a generally safe assumption. "Model space" is another term you might here.

Comment: Well phrased. "Model space" is a good term, since it cannot be misunderstood. Local, otoh - i often call something that happens in an isolated, specific place to happen in "it's local space", where "local" can be practically anything, is specific to the very calculation ongoing, is larger or smaller than model space and lacks an established name (like tangent space or world space). A good term for "model space" could be "objects local space". Someone said that everything is relative :-).